# Preventing Node.js from rendering embedded templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, underscore.js, ejs

I'm using ejs on the server to render entire html pages, but I'm also storing several small templates in the html so the client can render them later. How can I tell node.js to ignore these embedded templates?

My code on the server side:

```
app.get('/:template', function(req,res){
    res.render(req.params.template);
});
```

Sample html with an embedded template:

```
<body>
    <div><%= serverSideVariable %></div>
    <script type="text/template" id="embedded_template_01">
        <%= clientSideVariable %>
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here, how to make EJS not parse EJS code until it's on the clientside when you're also using EJS on the serverside ?

Comment: Yes, so I can store client templates directly in the html, and not ask the server for them separately.

Comment: I'm not sure you can? It's the same tags on the serverside and clientside for EJS, so not sure how you would tell EJS not to parse some of them on the serverside. There probably is a way, but I've never seen anything like that ?

Comment: You can set up EJS on the server side (or client side) to use different tags. The [ejs options](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#options) allow you to set the `open` and `close` tags.